# How to avoid a double call of scrollViewDidScroll() method while swiping the collectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiscrollview, uikit

I have created a User Onboarding as a `Collection View` with 5 cells (pages).

The `Collection View` has a `UIPageControl` which shows an active page user currently on and 2 `UIButtons` (previous and next) which needed to manually scroll the pages if user don't want to swipe.

Here is how I manage the buttons `IBAction` when user taps:

```
@IBAction func prevButtonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if currentPage != 0 {
        currentPage -= 1
        let indexPath = IndexPath(item: currentPage, section: 0)
        collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
    }
}

@IBAction func nextButtonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if currentPage == slides.count - 1 {
        //hide onboarding
    } else {
        currentPage += 1
        let indexPath = IndexPath(item: currentPage, section: 0)
        collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Also if user swipes a page instead of tap on buttons I use `scrollViewDidScroll()` method to update `UIPageControl` dot:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let visibleRectangle = CGRect(origin: collectionView.contentOffset, size: collectionView.bounds.size)
    let visiblePoint = CGPoint(x: visibleRectangle.midX, y: visibleRectangle.midY)
    currentPage = collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: visiblePoint)?.row ?? 0
}
```

The `currentPage` is a computed property:

```
private var currentPage = 0 {
    didSet {
        pageControl.currentPage = currentPage
        currentPage == 0 ? hidePreviousButton() : showPreviousButton()
    }
}
```

I have a problem: when tap on buttons I force `collectionView` to scroll and update `currentPage`, therefore `scrollViewDidScroll` called and `currentPage` updates again.

Because of that when I tap on buttons I can see that `UIPageControl` dot and `backButton` are flicker since the code runs twice:

```
    didSet {
        pageControl.currentPage = currentPage
        currentPage == 0 ? hidePreviousButton() : showPreviousButton()
    }
```

Here is a GIF with the problem: [GIF](https://cln.sh/ffXG9A)

How can I avoid the double call to `scrollViewDidScroll` when tap on buttons?

Comment: UIKit is event driven. You don't avoid calls, you cope with them. You position your code where your event will get called at the right time. Maybe didScroll wasn't a good choice of event?

Comment: Hei, Matt. Thank you for the reply. I need to use scrollViewDidScroll() because with this method I can update UIPageControl dot not when swipe is ended but as you can see the mid point becomes visible on the screen. I need to keep it...

Comment: Then you'll just have to devise some system of flags to track what's going on. But really I think it would be better to use the framework as it is intended to be used.

Comment: Actually it seems to me that your whole choice of collection view plus page control was wrong. Why didn't you use a UIPageViewController? It has a page control and is all set up for exactly what you're doing. I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: Thanks, Matt. I tried to create a boolean like buttonPressed and set it to true inside IBAction. And run the code inside scrollViewDidScroll() only if buttonPressed = false, but scrollViewDidScroll() runs regardless of that, so I continue to see the flickering

Comment: @artexhibit - yesterday I gave you the code to change the page control dot while the user is dragging using a `UIPageViewController` ... is there a specific reason you are trying to do this with a collection view instead?

Comment: Hei @DonMag. Yep, I switched to a collectionView because I have buttons and UIPageControl as a separate view, so no matter which page or item I show, the controls are always displayed. In case with UIPageViewController I should wrap it inside a container view and work with IBActions in a separate VC class than UIPageViewController. I wanted all controls and scroll code to have in one VC, that's why switched to collectionView. And I set up everything as needed except the above problem. Can you please check out is it possible to fix?

Comment: @artexhibit - put together a [mre] and post it somewhere like GitHub

Comment: @DonMag I setup a test project: https://github.com/artexhibit/TestCollectionViewOnboarding Please take a look at a string notes at the end of OnboardingVC. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a Bool var to your `OnboardingViewController`:

```
var programmedScroll: Bool = false
```

then, when prev or next button is tapped, instead of:

```
@IBAction func prevButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if currentPage != 0 {
        currentPage -= 1
        let indexPath = IndexPath(item: currentPage, section: 0)
        collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
    }
}
```

do this:

```
@IBAction func prevButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if currentPage != 0 {
        currentPage -= 1
        let indexPath = IndexPath(item: currentPage, section: 0)
        // instead of this
        //collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
        self.programmedScroll = true
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: false)
        }, completion: { _ in
            self.programmedScroll = false
        })
    }
}
```

Now your `scrollViewDidScroll` won't be called during that animation.

---

**Edit**

In `scrollViewDidScroll` implementation:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if !programmedScroll {
        let visibleRectangle = CGRect(origin: collectionView.contentOffset, size: collectionView.bounds.size)
        let visiblePoint = CGPoint(x: visibleRectangle.midX, y: visibleRectangle.midY)
        currentPage = collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: visiblePoint)?.row ?? 0
    }
}
```

---

**Edit 2**

Using the above approach resulted in a less-than-acceptable scroll effect, because a `UICollectionView` only renders cells that *will be displayed*.

When telling the collection view to `.scrollToItem` with `animated: false`, the collection view immediately drops the rendering of the cell that will *no longer be visible*.

So, we'll take the same approach, but find another way to "re-enable" the `scrollViewDidScroll` code after a Next / Prev button has called `.scrollToItem`.

In prev/next, let's still set `self.programmedScroll = true`, but instead of the animation block let's use the built-in animation:

```
@IBAction func prevButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if currentPage != 0 {
        currentPage -= 1
        let indexPath = IndexPath(item: currentPage, section: 0)
        // disable scrollViewDidScroll code execution
        self.programmedScroll = true
        collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
    }
}

@IBAction func nextButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if currentPage == slides.count - 1 {
        //hide onboarding
    } else {
        currentPage += 1
        let indexPath = IndexPath(item: currentPage, section: 0)
        // disable scrollViewDidScroll code execution
        self.programmedScroll = true
        collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
    }
}
```

then we need to "re-enable" the code to change the page control dot mid-way between cells when dragging, so we'll implement:

```
func scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    // re-enable execution of scrollViewDidScroll code
    programmedScroll = false
}
```

That should do it. I updated the repo at: https://github.com/DonMag/TestCollectionViewOnboarding

Comment: Yup, this is what I meant by "system of flags".

Comment: Hmm, I still see the flickering... What's the role of programmedScroll in this setup? How it affects the calling or non-calling of scrollViewDidScroll?

Comment: @artexhibit - whoops, see my **Edit**

Comment: Still the same. I tried almost the same solution (but without UIView.animate part) earlier and  a code inside scrollViewDidScroll runs anyway despite it has a programmedScroll flag...

Comment: @artexhibit - I forked your project and made those changes here: https://github.com/DonMag/TestCollectionViewOnboarding -- no flickering.

Comment: I found what it was: self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true) In this line you have animated: false. If you switch it to true you will have the flickering again

Comment: Is there any way to set `animated: true` and still don't have a flickering?

Comment: @artexhibit - why do you want to set `animated: true`?

Comment: When it’s set to false the transition animation between pages looks torn. When you swipe the image hides sharply…

Comment: @artexhibit - ah, I see what you mean. New **Edit 2** in my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, DonMag. Didn't know about `scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation` Works perfect!

Answer (score -1):

You can set tag for each collectionView and check tag of scrollView in scrollViewDidScroll.

Comment: Welcome to the Stackoverflow. Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information by providing more information or maybe with some code snippets. You can also use comment instead of an answer.